# Changing font of all UI elements using Text Kit

Tags: ios, ios7, uielement, textkit

One of the most common problem faced by iOS developers is to change the font of all the UI elements in one go.

With the introduction of [UIAppearance Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) setting the font did become very convenient, since then I've been using appearance to achieve this.

I was going through [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial) trying to understand Text Kit introduced in iOS 7. The tutorial uses subclass of [NSTextStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSTextStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to beautifully format the text.

Now I was just wondering if it is possible to change the font of UI elements by subclassing the NSTextStorage. I spend few hours trying to figure out where to start from but couldn't achieve anything so far. I appreciate if any one can give me a hint to where to start from and some tips to get this done.

I welcome all your suggestions and views on this.

Comment: what an issue with UITextField appearance? that did same result that you want.

Comment: @NitinGohel I don't have any problem with UIAppearance Protocols. They work like a charm. I was just wondering if this can be done in some other way.

Comment: Are you subclassing all text kit?

Comment: @iDev not the entire Text Kit. But in my opinion subcalssing NSTextStorage should do the the job.